# jpa @ManyToOne multiple entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wanna make common `MEMO` entity.
Table schema is like below

```
CREATE TABLE MEMO(
  resource_id int,
  resource_type varchar(10),
  content varchar(255)
)
```

Every entities can have relationship to this `MEMO` entity.
`resource_id` can have a primary key from another entities,
it means `resource_id` is foreign key that allows all entities.
And `resource_type` is entity's type. Yes, this is like discriminator.

I don't wanna make entities like `ITEM_MEMO`, `CATEGORY_MEMO`, `SCHEDULE_MEMO` ...
I think it's good until now, but now I realize that I don't know how to implements this table using JPA.

As you know, `@ManyToOne` can have one object.
But in my case, `resource_id` should have relationshipt to many entities.

So... is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use join tables instead? You could simply add `@OneToMany @JoinTable private Collection<Memo> memos` to all the relevant entities (the inverse association is, of course, impossible in this scenario).

Conversely, if you only need the `@ManyToOne` side, take a look at Hibernate's `@Any` annotation.

Comment: This is absolutely what I've been searching for. Thank you.